# how do i make a Tkinker widget ignore the width of the widget in the row above it(and just float to the left)?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I'm trying to create a calculator type of layout but the numbers mess up when I add the output field.

```
import Tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("BUTTON CALCULATOR")
window.geometry("400x400")


#----OutPut----
answer_output = tk.Text(master = window, height = 1, width = 20)
answer_output.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

#----BUTTONS----

buttonOne = tk.Button(text = "1")
buttonOne.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

numberTwo = tk.Button(text = "2")
numberTwo.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

numberThree = tk.Button(text = "3")
numberThree.grid(column = 2, row = 1)

window.mainloop()
```

How do I make 1, 2, and 3 sit next to each other on the left wide of the window?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is the missing `columnspan` for your textbox. The next thing you will probably want is `sticky` on the buttons so they stretch in the columns.

Take a look at the below example and let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("BUTTON CALCULATOR")
window.geometry("400x400")

answer_output = tk.Text(master=window, height=1, width=20)
answer_output.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3)

buttonOne = tk.Button(text="1")
buttonOne.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="ew")

numberTwo = tk.Button(text="2")
numberTwo.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="ew")

numberThree = tk.Button(text="3")
numberThree.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky="ew")

window.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]